# could not find function "melt" in Shiny App

Tags: shiny

I have an app designed that works perfectly fine on my local server. But when I deploy it I get the error "could not find function "melt"" in Shiny Server.
I did have the package installed.

Comment: Did you install it on the Shiny Server in a location that is visible from the `shiny` user (or any other user that you run Shiny Server with)?

Comment: It is the first thing in my server.r file. 
library(reshape)
library(reshape2)
shinyServer(function(input,output){...}

Comment: When you say `Shiny Server`, do you mean `shinyapps.io`?

Comment: I have written the code for melt () itself so now I am able to use it without the melt function. There are several problems with shinyapps.io as fr as packages are concerned. Thanks anyways.